# Row not deleting from SQLite Database

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have an `ArrayList` that is part of a training log that I am working on. I have set it up so that when I click on one of the cells of the `ListView` (in **TrainingLog.java**), it should delete the row from the database, and thus the cell when the table is reloaded, but it is not having any effect. What am I doing wrong (is this an issue with my database **DBAdapter.java**?), and is there any better way to approach the issue?

**TrainingLog.java** :

```
public class TrainingLog extends Fragment {

    ListView lv;
    ArrayList<String> players = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    ArrayAdapter<String> clearAdapter;
    ArrayList<String> details = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> dates = new ArrayList<String>();



    public TrainingLog() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }



    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_training_log, container, false);
        lv = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.myListView);
        final DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this.getActivity());


        setHasOptionsMenu(true);

        players.clear();
        details.clear();
        dates.clear();

        //OPEN
        db.openDB();



        //RETRIEVE
        Cursor c=db.getAllNames();

        while(c.moveToNext())
        {
            String name=c.getString(1);
            players.add(name);
            String pos=c.getString(2);
            details.add(pos);
            String date=c.getString(3);
            dates.add(date);
        }

        db.close();

        String[] playerArray = new String[players.size()];
        playerArray = players.toArray(playerArray);

        String[] detailArray =  new String[details.size()];
        detailArray = details.toArray(detailArray);

        String[] datesArray = new String[dates.size()];
        datesArray = dates.toArray(datesArray);

        ListAdapter myAdapter = new TrainingAdapter(this.getActivity(), playerArray, detailArray, datesArray);
        lv.setAdapter(myAdapter);

        final String[] finalPlayerArray = playerArray;
        final String[] finalDetailArray = detailArray;
        final String[] finalDateArray = datesArray;

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                String player = finalPlayerArray[position];
                String detail = finalDetailArray[position];
                String onedate = finalDateArray[position];


                 //Toast.makeText(getActivity(),player, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                //OPEN
                db.openDB();

                //Remove

                db.deleteInterestID(position);
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();



                //CLOSE DB
                db.close();

                //Reload

                players.clear();
                details.clear();
                dates.clear();

                //OPEN
                db.openDB();

                //RETRIEVE
                Cursor c=db.getAllNames();

                while(c.moveToNext())
                {
                    String name=c.getString(1);
                    players.add(name);
                    String pos=c.getString(2);
                    details.add(pos);
                    String date=c.getString(3);
                    dates.add(date);
                }

                db.close();

                String[] playerArray = new String[players.size()];
                playerArray = players.toArray(playerArray);

                String[] detailArray =  new String[details.size()];
                detailArray = details.toArray(detailArray);

                String[] datesArray = new String[dates.size()];
                datesArray = dates.toArray(datesArray);

                ListAdapter myAdapter = new TrainingAdapter(getActivity(), playerArray, detailArray, datesArray);
                lv.setAdapter(myAdapter);

            }
        });

        return rootView;
    }


    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();


        final DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this.getActivity());

        players.clear();
        details.clear();
        dates.clear();

        ///OPEN
        db.openDB();



        //RETRIEVE
        Cursor c=db.getAllNames();

        while(c.moveToNext())
        {
            String name=c.getString(1);
            players.add(name);
            String pos=c.getString(2);
            details.add(pos);
            String date=c.getString(3);
            dates.add(date);
        }

        db.close();

        String[] playerArray = new String[players.size()];
        playerArray = players.toArray(playerArray);

        String[] detailArray =  new String[details.size()];
        detailArray = details.toArray(detailArray);

        String[] datesArray = new String[dates.size()];
        datesArray = dates.toArray(datesArray);

        ListAdapter myAdapter = new TrainingAdapter(this.getActivity(), playerArray, detailArray, datesArray);
        lv.setAdapter(myAdapter);

        final String[] finalPlayerArray = playerArray;

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                String player = finalPlayerArray[position];
                //Toast.makeText(getActivity(),player, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(
            Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.traning_menu_itemdetail, menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // handle item selection
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_add:
                Intent trainingCreateIntent = new Intent (getContext(), TrainingLogCreate.class);
                startActivity(trainingCreateIntent);
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
}
```

**DBAdapter**:

```
public class DBAdapter {

    //COLUMNS
    static final String ROWID="id";
    static final String NAME = "name";
    static final String POSITION = "position";
    static final String DATE = "date";

    //DB PROPERTIES
    static final String DBNAME="m_DB";
    static final String TBNAME="m_TB";
    static final int DBVERSION='1';

    static final String CREATE_TB="CREATE TABLE m_TB(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
            + "name TEXT NOT NULL,position TEXT NOT NULL,date TEXT NOT NULL);";

    final Context c;
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    DBHelper helper;

    public DBAdapter(FragmentActivity ctx) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

        this.c=ctx;
        helper=new DBHelper(c);
    }

    // INNER HELPER DB CLASS
    private static class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
    {

        public DBHelper(Context context ) {
            super(context, DBNAME, null, DBVERSION);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

            try
            {
                db.execSQL(CREATE_TB);
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Log.w("DBAdapetr","Upgrading DB");

            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS m_TB");

            onCreate(db);
        }

    }

    // OPEN THE DB
    public DBAdapter openDB()
    {
        try
        {
            db=helper.getWritableDatabase();

        }catch(SQLException e)
        {
            Toast.makeText(c, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        return this;
    }


    //CLOSE THE DB
    public void close()
    {
        helper.close();
    }

    //INSERT INTO TABLE
    public long add(String name,String pos, String date)
    {
        try
        {
            ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
            cv.put(NAME, name);
            cv.put(POSITION, pos);
            cv.put(DATE, date);

            return db.insert(TBNAME, ROWID, cv);

        }catch(SQLException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return 0;
    }

    //REMOVE FROM TABLE
    public void deleteInterestID(int id) {
        /* SQLiteDatabase db=helper.getWritableDatabase();
        String[] whereArgs = {name};
        db.delete(TBNAME, NAME+"=?", whereArgs); */

        SQLiteDatabase db=helper.getWritableDatabase();
        db.delete(TBNAME, NAME + "=?", new String[]{String.valueOf(id)});
        db.close();



    }

    //GET ALL VALUES

    public Cursor getAllNames()
    {
        String[] columns={ROWID,NAME,POSITION,DATE};

        return db.query(TBNAME, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
    }





}
```

**EDIT: CRASH ERROR**:

```
02-27 12:57:00.985 20189-20189/com.hardingsoftware.hrcfitness E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                            Process: com.hardingsoftware.hrcfitness, PID: 20189
                                                                            android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x6
                                                                                at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:299)
                                                                                at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:285)
                                                                                at com.hardingsoftware.hrcfitness.TrainingLog$1.onItemClick(TrainingLog.java:104)
                                                                                at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:305)
                                                                                at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1146)
                                                                                at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3053)
                                                                                at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:3860)
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Comment: use `Toast` to display the `position`. Does the `id` you want to delete same as `position` ?

Comment: I'll try this, and get back.

Comment: it made no difference- toast didn't even print and appear.

Comment: simply add a Toast there. If list is clicked, does it print any message ?

Comment: it does not print any message when clicked.

Comment: change   `lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()` to `lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()`

Comment: it throws 'cannot resolve symbol 'OnItemClickListener'' and suggests adding AdapterView as it was before. I think this may be the issue though, that it simply can't find position because the cell is not being pointed to correctly... not sure how to fix that though.

Comment: How about put the Toast just after onItemClick ?

Comment: it still doesn't appear, even when 'Toast.makeText(getActivity(),position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();' is placed as first priority right inside the method :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your delete method signature to `public void deleteInterestID(string pos) {` and query to

```
db.delete(TBNAME, POSITION + "=?", new String[]{pos});
```

and then

```
 db.deleteInterestID(position);
```

to

```
 db.deleteInterestID(finalDetailArray[position]);
```

**Update**

Remove method `onResume` completely. You already have that code in `onCreateView`. No need to write twice. You are again adding listener here, which is removing one added in `onCreateView` in which you are doing the delete operation.

Comment: I had to create finalDetailArray, and made it 'db.deleteInterestID(finalDetailArray.get(position));' , but  now it is throwing 'can't resolve method get(int)', and is throwing the error that 'symbol notifyDataSetChanged cannot be resolved'

Comment: @JohnHarding: My type sorry about that. Use `db.deleteInterestID(detailArray[position]);`. And forget about notifydatasetchanged part. See updated answer.

Comment: the edit fixed those errors, thanks for that, but it still does not delete the row in the database, as the cell is still present in the ListView when the view is reloaded.

Comment: I guess you remove the last two lines as I suggest earlier. You need to add  those two lines back again.

Comment: I did add them, there is still no effect.

Comment: @JohnHarding: Try removing (or commenting) method `onResume` completely. You already have that code in `onCreateView`. No need to write twice. You are again adding listener here, which is removing one added in `onCreateView`

Comment: I removed the method, and now when I click on a cell the the app crashes with the error 'FATAL EXCEPTION: main' and '  android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x6' That's progress though, any ideas?

Comment: Definitely. Please post the complete error log in your post.

Comment: Interger in Toast message has a different meaning. Change `Toast.makeText(getActivity(), position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();` to `Toast.makeText(getActivity(), position + "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`. or use any random text, rather than `position`.

Comment: Thanks, it's working now! I added my on resume() method and updated it with the same content as my main method, and now everything is working great. thanks again!

Comment: @JohnHarding: Good to know. Please don't think rude of me but your code need many changes. Everything is working but this is not efficient code. There are many variable and lines of code without which you could have achieved it. I would suggest you to keep a copy of this class and when you get time, try to improve it.

Comment: Completely understood. I'm still learning my way around both android and java, so a lot of this was a culmination of other peoples projects. Regardless, I'll take a look at it and try to cut it down. Thank you once again!

Answer (score 1):

By looking at DBAdapter, you have a table with column id, name, position and date.

In **TrainingLog**, you passing the `position` and want the column which has value same as `position` get deleted in **DBAdapter**. Which column you pointed to ? `position` or `id` ?

If you want delete the value in `position` column, change this line  `db.delete(TBNAME, NAME + "=?", new String[]{String.valueOf(id)});` to  `db.delete(TBNAME, POSITION + "=?", new String[]{String.valueOf(id)});` if id, then change `POSITION` to `ROWID`.

Comment: I tried that and it still had no effect. I want to delete the entire row that has the same value for position.

Answer (score -1):

All cruds in the database use transaction -> db.beginTransaction() -> db.setTransactionSuccessful() -> db.endTransaction(), so the final commit can happen.